# Can i use WySIWYG Text Editor in add/edit option of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg

Can I use WySIWYG Text Editor in add/edit option of jqgrid
Or is there any editor which I can use with jqgrid providing same functionality of WySIWYG Text Editor.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7?

Comment: It is Free-jqGrid